# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle: BriefComposition

Tags: android, android-room

When i upgraded my sqlite, I got following error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle: BriefComposition(com.zhixin.wedeep.homepage.data.model.BriefComposition).
     Expected:
    TableInfo{name='BriefComposition', columns={cover=Column{name='cover', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, duration=Column{name='duration', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, downloadURL=Column{name='downloadURL', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, tag=Column{name='tag', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, isNeedVip=Column{name='isNeedVip', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
     Found:
    TableInfo{name='BriefComposition', columns={cover=Column{name='cover', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, duration=Column{name='duration', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, downloadURL=Column{name='downloadURL', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, tag=Column{name='tag', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
        at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade(RoomOpenHelper.java:103)
```

I have compared those two `TableInfo` and sure the only difference between two `TableInfo` is new
property `isNeedVip` added in version 2.

This is my `BriefComposition` Entity

```kotlin
@Entity
data class BriefComposition(
    val cover: String,
    val duration: String,
    @PrimaryKey val id: String,
    val tag: String?,
    val title: String,
    val downloadURL: String,
    val isNeedVip:Boolean? //add on version 2
) : Serializable {
    
    companion object{
    
        val MIGRATION_1_2 = object : Migration(1, 2) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                database.execSQL(
                    "ALTER TABLE 'BriefComposition' ADD COLUMN 'isNeedVip' INTEGER"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This my `Database` class

```kotlin
@Database(
    entities = [
        Composition::class,
        CachedCompositions::class,
        BrowseRecord::class,
        Comment::class,
        BriefComposition::class
    ],
    version = 2,
    exportSchema = true
)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class HomePageDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun compositionDao(): CompositionDao
    abstract fun compositionsDao(): CompositionsDao
    abstract fun commentDao(): CommentDao

    companion object {

        const val DB_NAME = "homepage-db"

        // For Singleton instantiation
        @Volatile
        private var instance: HomePageDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): HomePageDatabase {
            return instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance ?: buildDatabase(context).also { instance = it }
            }
        }

        // Create and pre-populate the database. See this article for more details:
        // https://medium.com/google-developers/7-pro-tips-for-room-fbadea4bfbd1#4785
        private fun buildDatabase(context: Context): HomePageDatabase {
            return Room.databaseBuilder(context, HomePageDatabase::class.java, DB_NAME)
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .addMigrations(BriefComposition.MIGRATION_1_2, Composition.MIGRATION_1_2)
                .build()
        }
    }
}
```

I have no ideas why this happened, cause i have added all necessary `migration` to Database Builder. What's more, When i debug my code, i found `database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE 'BriefComposition' ADD COLUMN 'isNeedVip' INTEGER")` didn't execute

Comment: Your post shows a second migration for version 1 to 2, `Composition.MIGRATION_1_2`.  What does it do?  Why two migrate functions for same versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The migrations added to a `RoomDatabase` are stored in a [MigrationContainer](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.MigrationContainer).  The documentation for function `addMigrations()` states:

> Adds the given migrations to the list of available migrations. If two
> migrations have the same start-end versions, the latter migration
> overrides the previous one.

You have two migrations for version 1 to 2: `BriefComposition.MIGRATION_1_2` and `Composition.MIGRATION_1_2`.  The migration for Composition is overriding the one for BriefComposition, so `BriefComposition.MIGRATION_1_2` is not called and column `isNeedVip` is not added.

Comment: Thank u, it works. At first i think two migrations that have same start-end versions can work together, so i won't upgrade database version too fast. For the moment it seems that i must  upgrade my database version to 3

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the default value of `isNeedVip` column your migration script is like :

```
val MIGRATION_1_2 = object : Migration(1, 2) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                database.execSQL(
                        "ALTER TABLE 'BriefComposition' ADD COLUMN 'isNeedVip' INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1")
            }
        }
```

you can refer the [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#handle-missing-migrations) for more detail

Comment: but my property ```isNeedVip``` Boolean is nullable